# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, this is irritating me

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to map the title in the form of integer using list.

```
title_map = {'Mr':0, 'Miss':1, 'Mrs':2, 'Master':3, 'Dr':3, 'Rev':3, 'Major':3, 'Col':3, 'Mlle':3, 'Capt':3, 'Jonkheer':3, 'Lady':3,'Don':3, 'Mme':3, 'Ms':3, 'Countess':3,'Sir':3}

for dataset in train_test_data():
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].map(title_map)
```

> `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>   <ipython-input-63-e6e2af2d1334> in <module>()
>         1 title_map = {'Mr':0, 'Miss':1, 'Mrs':2, 'Master':3, 'Dr':3, 'Rev':3, 'Major':3, 'Col':3, 'Mlle':3, 'Capt':3, 'Jonkheer':3, 'Lady':3,'Don':3, 'Mme':3, 'Ms':3, 'Countess':3,'Sir':3}
>         2 
>   ----> 3 for dataset in train_test_data():
>         4     dataset['title'] = dataset['Title'].map(title_map)`
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

So for future reference you can use backticks to format code in stack overflow.

Anyway,you are getting that error because you are passing a list as the first argument to the map function. The map function takes a function and applies that function to some iterable object. If you include more details about what you are expecting to be in `dataset['Title']` after the loop, I may be able to help you out more.

[Docs for python map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

[Formatting in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)